# vectors and frequency search

Tags: c++, vector, binary

I am creating a program that records the frequency of a number in an existing file.  My vectors name is test, so why does it say "test" isn't defined?

It might be something small im missing....

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
string fileName;
int aTest;

cout << "Enter a File Name:";
cin >>fileName;

ifstream inFile (fileName.c_str());
if (! inFile)
{
cout << "!!Error in opening file 'test.dat'"<< endl;
    }

while( inFile >> aTest)

    vector <int> test (101, 0)

    test[aTest]++;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your vector outside the `while` loop and you should add proper `{}` to make your logic correct.

Try:

```
 vector <int> test(101, 0); //^missing semicolon
 while( inFile >> aTest) {
    test[aTest]++;
  }
```

Meanwhile, don't use `using namespace std`, which is considered bad practice.

Besides:

```
  #include <ostream> //^^remove one of them, don't include unnecessary headers
  #include <iostream>
```

Comment: @SabrinaFolzeratti: the point to not use `using namespace...` is a good one. It is acceptable to use `using std::string;` and then use string or vector and so on as long as you provide an individual `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error and `test` should be defined outside of the loop.

```
  vector<int> test(101, 0); // Removed whitespace and added semi-colon.
  while(inFile >> aTest) {  // Use braces for a new block.
    test[aTest]++;
  }
```